# Add affiliate URL query parameter to all links of a domain on a single page in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am preparing a page on my wordpress site where I will post coupons and product urls for a website I am an affiliate of.

Instead of creating affiliate links by hand on every URL, I would like to automatically add the affiliate query parameter on every URL of this particular domain.

The urls might be:

```
example.com
example.com/
example.com/cell-phones-c_11293/
example.com/cell-phones/pp_617010.html?wid=4
```

The query parameter I want to add is ?lkid=12345678 (the same for every URL).

```
example.com?lkid=12345678
example.com/?lkid=12345678
example.com/cell-phones-c_11293/?lkid=12345678
example.com/cell-phones/pp_617010.html?wid=4&lkid=10823628
```

I want this functionality only for this particular page, not for every post on Wordpress, so I wouldn't like to add the code to the functions.php, or install a plugin just for this single page.

Is it possible to add it as a header or body script to the page through the "Scripts" screen option at the editor?

I have found the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861379/3083890),

```
<script>
var $links = $('a'); // get all anchor tags

// loop through each anchor tag
$.each($links, function(index, item){
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); // var for value of href attribute
            // use regex to match your domain
            var pattern = new RegExp(/(example.com\/)(.*)/i);
            if(pattern.test(url))
                $(this).attr('href', url + '?lkid=12345678');
                // append ?lkid=12345678 if url contains example
});
</script>
```

And the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/3083890)

```
<script>
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}
</script>
```

...but I unfortunately I don't know enough programming to make them work for my case.

Comment: I've edited my post and added a solution that works both for links that already have a query string, and those that don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code adds the parameter if it doesn't already have a query string, and will parse, add the parameter, and re-encode for links that already have a query string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>
        <a href="//www.google.com?test=1">Test</a>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/?test=1">Test</a>
        <a href="www.example.com?test=1">Test</a>
        <a href="../?test=1&another=2">Test</a>
        <a href="?test=1&another=2">Test</a>
        <script>
            // parseQuery: Originally from StackOverflow of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419367/2529423
            function parseQuery(qstr) {
                var query = {};
                var a = (qstr[0] === '?' ? qstr.substr(1) : qstr).split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    var b = a[i].split('=');
                    query[decodeURIComponent(b[0])] = decodeURIComponent(b[1] || '');
                }
                return query;
            }

            // encodeQuery originally from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/2529423
            function encodeQuery(obj) {
              var str = [];
              for(var p in obj)
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                  str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                }
              return str.join("&");
            }

            function addQueryParameterToDomain(key, value, conditionDomain) {
                var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]'),
                    linksLength = links.length,
                    index,
                    queryIndex,
                    queryString,
                    query,
                    url,
                    domain,
                    colonSlashSlash;

                // Iterate through and add query paramter
                for(index = 0; index < linksLength; ++index) {
                    url = links[index].href,
                    queryIndex = url.indexOf('?'),
                    colonSlashSlash = url.indexOf('://');

                    domain = url.substring(colonSlashSlash + 3);
                    domain = domain.substring(0, domain.indexOf('/'));

                    if(domain !== conditionDomain) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if(queryIndex === -1) {
                        url += '?' + key + '=' + value;
                    } else {
                        queryString = url.substring(queryIndex);
                        url = url.substring(0, queryIndex);
                        query = parseQuery(queryString);

                        query[key] = value;

                        url += '?' + encodeQuery(query);
                    }

                    links[index].href = url;
                }
            }

            jQuery(function() {
                addQueryParameterToDomain('lkid', '12345678', 'example.com');
                addQueryParameterToDomain('lkid', '12345678', 'www.example.com');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

All you'll need to do is replace the script you have with the contents of the `<script>` tag above, and bob's your uncle.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome code. Just one little request: is it possible to add the query on only the example.com links? Because the current code adds it to every link on the page, the menu links, the ad links, the lot.

Comment: @AngelosKyritsis, just realised you even said that in your question. Sorry about that, I sometimes don't read things properly.

Answer (score 0):

First answer looks to work except if the href already has some parameters (?x=y). Also, it's advisable to put jQuery code inside .ready function. And last, in wordpress by default you need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` alias, or pass `$` into the function, which I'm doing here:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var $links = $('a'); // get all anchor tags

    // loop through each anchor tag
    $.each($links, function(index, item){
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); // var for value of href attribute
            // use regex to match your domain
            var pattern = new RegExp(/(example.com\/)(.*)/i);
            if(pattern.test(url))
                var chr = url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&"; // will be "&" if "?" in url
                $(this).attr('href', url + chr + 'lkid=12345678');
                // append ?lkid=12345678 if url contains example
    });
});
</script>
```

Give it a shot and if it works for you I'll make some improvements for the parameters.

Comment: This still won't work if the link already has query string parameters, I've edited my posted and added my script now. As `?test=1&another=2?lkid=12345678` is not a valid query string.

Comment: I'm aware of that... read the first line of my answer. Also OP said he doesn't like to add the code to the functions.php.

Comment: Read my answer again, it doesn't use PHP now.

Comment: It works, @yezzz. If you can add a little something to check if the link already has query string parameters, it will be perfect.

Comment: I'll put in a simple check for '?' being in the url. Not foolproof, so you may want to go with phpdev answer